# Programatically inject packets to virtual interface

Tags: linux, networking, libpcap

We are currently developing a prototype aiming to "bridge" a local virtual interface in Linux to an API sending/receiving Ethernet packets using proprietary hardware. The idea is in the end to use standard libraries and tools transparently with this proprietary hardware.

As a first step ensuring that what we want to do is indeed possible, we made a first version of the prototype bridging a virtual interface to an actual Ethernet interface using libpcap. Here is what we did :

- create a local dummy interface on PC1 with a MAC/IP address (192.168.0.1)
- configure PC2 with an IP on the same network (192.168.0.2)
- link PC1 and PC2 using a non-configured interface on PC1
- use a simple 'bridge' program on PC1, developed with libpcap that listens on one interface and inject packets on the second one (using pcap_sendpacket), and the other way around, to bridge dummy interface and actual Ethernet interface
- launch ping from PC1 to PC2

When spying on the dummy interface on PC1, we observe ICMP requests and responses, so the bridge program works OK, but the ping tool does not get the ICMP responses at application level.

I'm guessing we inject packets too late in the kernel routing process...or something.

Do you know how to do this properly? Maybe use an alternate type of virtual interface? (bridge, tun/tap...) It cannot be a full system/command line solution since in the end we want to bridge packets to a proprietary API and not to an Ethernet interface, so we need programmatic access to the packets (hence libpcap).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You're looking for a tun/tap interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with dummy module interfaces in Linux. They can only transmit packets 'downwards', from the kernel to the network hardware device. And, as in the case of dummy interfaces there is no hardware device, packets are discarded when they reach the bottom of this path (`dummy_xmit` function). You can treat it as a one-way sink.

Here is the call graph:

```
                          [applications]
                          [tcp/ip stack]  
                                 |
                                 |
                                 v
pcap_sendpacket -> tpacket_snd -> dev_queue_xmit -> dev_hard_start_xmit -> xmit_one -> netdev_start_xmit -> ndo_start_xmit -> dummy_xmit -> dev_kfree_skb
                                                                                    |
                                                                                    |
pcap_next <- tpacket_rcv <- prot_hook.func <- deliver_skb <-dev_queue_xmit_nit <-----
```

So, in your case, ping requests from ping application go into the device transmission path. They are discarded at the end of this path, but before that, they are copied and these copies are being passed into the pcap bridge listening on the interface. Bridge application forwards them to the PC2. PC2 answers ping requests and send responses back to the bridge application. The bridge application injects these responses into the device transmission path, they go downwards it and are discarded. But before that, they are copied to all pcap listeners, including tcpdump you use to spy and observe traffic, but excluding your bridge application which injected them:

```
++ net/core/dev.c
@@ void dev_queue_xmit_nit(struct sk_buff *skb, struct net_device *dev)
    ...
    /* Never send packets back to the socket
     * they originated from - MvS (miquels@drinkel.ow.org)
     */
    if (skb_loop_sk(ptype, skb))
        continue;
```

This is why you see both requests and responses. But responses are not being passed up to the kernel TCP/IP stack and ping application, because this is not possible with dummy interface. They are transmitted downwards to `dummy_xmit` and discarded.

Therefore, in your case, you should use either TAP interface, or, if you want to still use pcap to exchange packets, veth virtual links.